# Chrome TLS 1.3 no TLS resumption with not secure connections

Tags: tls

I am testing TLS 1.3 on a slower IoT device (120Mhz ARM). In my tests Chrome with TLS 1.3 will not allow TLS resumption (Session Tickets) when you have an not secure connection e.g. because of an user accepted self-signed certificate. Additionally you will see almost the doubled number of TCP connections when loading from the website that has an invalid certificate (wrong alternate name or root not trusted).

Has anybody an idea, if that is intended by Chrome? There is no TLS resumption problem with TLS 1.2, or Firefox TLS 1.3.

Comment: A total guess: maybe Chrome wants to see if the certificate problem will be fixed, and it can't do that if it uses resumption.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical behavior of Chrome if the certificate is not trusted but the user has just skipped the warning. Skipping warnings is a bad idea anyway so you better import the certificate explicitly as trusted.